# Deploying your own virtual machine on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have build a small Operating System using COSMOS(C# Open Source Managed Operating System), which works fine on VMWare Workstation. For the sake of fun, I wanted to know that is it possible to deploy ISO image of my Operating System as a virtual machine in Windows Azure, so that i could access it remotely via  RDP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it's possible, but you'll need to create a .vhd with your iso file.

Useful links

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/

PS: Let me know if it works.